# My JButtons will not work, what is wrong with my GUI application?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have tried to figure this out for about 2 hours but can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. If anyone could help me that would be great. Below is the code and if you would run it and click on "Create" or "Exit" neither will work.

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField; 
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;
private JTextField textField_9;
private JTextField textField_10;
protected String msg;
private JLabel label;

/**
 * Launch Application.
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ProjectPart1 frame = new ProjectPart1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    }

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public ProjectPart1() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 795, 555);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    // html tag
    msg = "";
    HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();

    // it prints html message and java text
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(); //msgPane
    textPane.setBackground(Color.blue); 
    textPane.setBounds(359, 11, 410, 494);
    textPane.setEditorKit(kit);
    textPane.setText(msg);
    contentPane.add(textPane);

    // Prints the text in the label
    JLabel madLib = new JLabel("Mad LIB");
    madLib.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    madLib.setBounds(49, 4, 126, 32);
    contentPane.add(madLib);

    //Prints the text in the label
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter your name ");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label1.setBounds(10, 47, 135, 15);
    contentPane.add(label1);

    // Generates textField
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(150, 47, 95, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    // Prints the text in the label
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter a random name ");
    label2.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label2.setBounds(10, 73, 206, 14);
    contentPane.add(label2);

    // Generates input1
    JTextField input1 = new JTextField();
    input1.setBounds(150, 71, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(input1); //frame.add
    input1.setColumns(10);

    // Prints the text in label
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Enter a state (EX. NJ) ");
    label3.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label3.setBounds(10, 99, 152, 14);
    contentPane.add(label3);

    // Generates input2
    JTextField input2 = new JTextField();
    input2.setBounds(150, 97, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(input2);
    input2.setColumns(10);

    //Prints the text in label
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Enter an adjective ");
    label4.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label4.setBounds(10, 124, 174, 15);
    contentPane.add(label4);

    //Generates input3
    JTextField input3 = new JTextField();
    input3.setBounds(150, 122, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(input3);
    input3.setColumns(10);

    // Prints the text in label
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Enter a noun ");
    label5.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label5.setBounds(10, 151, 152, 14);
    contentPane.add(label5);

    // Prints the text in label
    JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Enter a verb ");
    label6.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label6.setBounds(10, 176, 183, 14 );
    contentPane.add(label6);

    // Prints the text in label
    JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Enter a noun ");
    label7.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label7.setBounds(10, 201, 157, 14);
    contentPane.add(label7);

    // Prints the text in label
    JLabel label8 = new JLabel("Enter a verb ");
    label8.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label8.setBounds(10, 226, 135, 14);
    contentPane.add(label8);

    // Prints the text in label
    JLabel label9 = new JLabel("Enter an adjective ");
    label9.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label9.setBounds(10, 274, 189, 14);
    contentPane.add(label9);

    //Result print
    label = new JLabel();


    label.setBounds(200, 150, 50, 50);
    contentPane.add(label);

    // Prints the date and time
    DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();

    JButton btnCreateMSG = new JButton("Create");
    btnCreateMSG.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String msg1 = msg;

            // Get text from user html inside java
            String txte1 = "<b>" + textField.getText() + "</b>" + "<br />" + "128 Congress Street" + "<br />" + "Jersey City NJ 07003";
            String txte2 = "<p>March 14, 2017 </p>";
            String txte3 = "" + "<br />" + "<b>" + textField_1.getText() + "</b>" + "<br />" + "184 Newark Street" + "<br />" + "Jersey City";
            String txte4 = "<p>Dear <b>" + textField_1.getText() + "</b></p>";
            String txte5 = "<p> Hey, I am writing this <b>" + textField_9.getText() + 
                    "</b> to invite you to my house during this spring break. Since we did a lot of work during the semester"
                    + textField_5.getText() + "</b>, but we would also do a lot of fun activities like playing games <b>" + textField_8.getText()
                    + "</b>, going out for dinner and travel to <b>" + textField_2.getText()
                    + "</b>. We will also study together for <b>" + textField_7.getText()
                    + "</b> exam, and we will also read funny <b>" + textField_4.getText()
                    + "</b> as well. I guarantee that you would have an amazing spring break. It would be <b>"
                    + textField_3.getText() + "</b> if you come to my house on <b>" + dt.format(date)
                    + "</b>, and I am <b>" + textField_10.getText()
                    + "</b> to meet you over the spring break. See you soon.</p>";
            String txte6 = "<p> Best Regards,</p>";
            String txte7 = "<p><b>" + "<br />" + "" + textField.getText() + "</b></p>";

            msg1 += txte1;
            msg1 += txte2;
            msg1 += txte3;
            msg1 += txte4;
            msg1 += txte5;
            msg1 += txte6;
            msg1 += txte7;

            madLib.setText(msg1);

        }
    });

    btnCreateMSG.setBounds(26,  311,  100,  30);
    contentPane.add(btnCreateMSG);

    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

    btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            // A reset button
            textField.setText("");
            textField_1.setText("");
            textField_2.setText("");
            textField_3.setText("");
            textField_4.setText("");
            textField_5.setText("");
            textField_7.setText("");
            textField_8.setText("");
            textField_9.setText("");
            textField_10.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnExit.setBounds(235,  309,  95,  32);
    contentPane.add(btnExit);

    // Generates input4
    JTextField textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setBounds(150, 149, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setColumns(10);

    // Generates input5
    JTextField textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setBounds(150, 174, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_5);
    textField_5.setColumns(10);

    // Generates input6
    JTextField textField_7 = new JTextField();
    textField_7.setBounds(150, 199, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_7);
    textField_7.setColumns(10);

    // Generates input7
    JTextField textField_8 = new JTextField();
    textField_8.setBounds(150, 224, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_8);
    textField_8.setColumns(10);

    // Generates input8
    JTextField textField_9 = new JTextField();
    textField_9.setBounds(150, 247, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_9);
    textField_9.setColumns(10);

    // Generates input9
    JTextField textField_10 = new JTextField();
    textField_10.setBounds(150, 272, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_10);
    textField_10.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` because `textField_1` is never initialised

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry I still don't get the issue.  Every time I change something and run the code a new error on different lines come up.

Comment: You define `textField_1`, but never assign it a value, in fact, most of the fields are never assigned a value because you started doing `JTextField input1 = new JTextField();`

Comment: John, read the answers given to the [duplicate question used to close your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I figured it out thank you ver much :)

Comment: I figured it out thank you ver much :)..it turns out I made a few simple errors in adding Jtextfield where I did not need to as well as a set.Text mistake.